# convert QImage to char*

Tags: c++, image, qt, type-conversion

I capture image and use QByteArray to store and save image in it:

```
QImage image(WEB_SCREENSHOT_WIDTH, page.viewportSize().height()/*65000,*/, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
QByteArray bytes;
QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG");
```

and I want to pass QByteArray to char* and return it at the end of the  function like this:

```
unsigned char* char_return = (unsigned char*)bytes.data();
```

I have to do this because my rest of program is C base...
But at the end the file that saved can not be opened
help me please

**EDIT**:
Minimal function is like this:

```
unsigned char* web_screenshot::get_web_image(){
  QImage image(WEB_SCREENSHOT_WIDTH, page.viewportSize().height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
  QByteArray bytes;
  QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
  buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  image.save(&buffer, "PNG");
  unsigned char* char_return = (unsigned char*)bytes.data(); 
  return char_return;
}
```

Comment: Well if you want to return a memory pointer from your function, you will have to allocate it, you won't be able to return directly `bytes.data()` since it's local to your function. But, I'm only guessing. To really help you you need to post a [MCVE].

Comment: I do my best for edit. hope you can help me now

Comment: This seems to be C++, not C.

Comment: Qt is c++ base but Q*anything* is Qt variable not in c++

Comment: But `get_web_image` is a member of class `web_screenshot` and can't be called directly from `C` (as far as I'm aware).  Also, as pointed out by @purplepsycho, the `QByteArray` goes out of scope at the end of the function so you're returning a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a deep copy of bytes.data() like this:

```
unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *) malloc unsigned char(bytes.size());
memcpy(data, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(bytes.data()), bytes.size());
```

**Update:**

Below, you can see a functioning example where a copy of original image data is used for loading a new image which is shown on the UI:

```
unsigned char* deepCopyImageData(int &size){
  QImage image("test.png"); // test image
  QByteArray bytes;
  QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
  buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  image.save(&buffer, "PNG");
  buffer.close();

  unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *) malloc(bytes.size());
  memcpy(data, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(bytes.data()), bytes.size());
  size = bytes.size();
  return data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    int size;
    unsigned char *data = deepCopyImageData(size);

    QImage image;
    if(!image.loadFromData(data,size))
        qWarning("Image loading failed");

    free(data); data = nullptr;
    QLabel *label = new QLabel();
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    label->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Note that the `QByteArray` may contain null characters so using `strcpy` will be unreliable -- use `memcpy` or `std::copy` instead.  Also, given that the calling `C` code might be responsible for ownership of the returned pointer is might be better to use `malloc` rather than `new` in this instance.

Comment: First of all Thank you for your answer

Comment: no, unfortunately it didn't work! and i should say that for malloc you should say what type you want to allocate like: (char*) malloc (sizeof char*)

Comment: My bad, added casting from malloc void pointer. I also added an example where deep copying is used.